# mysqli query duplicating when trying to enter data in two different tables

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I have a form where a teacher can create a new school as a user and that teacher's school gets an ID. So I check the database to make sure the id doesn't already exist in the "school" table. If it does I get that school ID so the teacher can create a profile with it. If it doesn't already exist then a new one is created and entered into both the "school" table AND the "users" table for that teacher's school.

It's working fine, only except that every time the form is filled out the data is entered twice, but only in the "USERS" table. In the "school" table it is entered once as it should be.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? I have been looking for weeks.

**code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  


    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$lastname);
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$phone);
    $school=$_POST['school'];
    $school = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$school);
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$address);
    $region=$_POST['region'];
    $region = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$region);
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$state);
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$zip);
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

      //GET STATE NAME
      $getState = "SELECT state from `states` WHERE id= '$state'";
      $stateRes = mysqli_query($con, $getState);
      $stateRow = mysqli_fetch_array($stateRes);
      $stateName = $stateRow['state'];


      //CHECK SCHOOL

    $checkSchool = "SELECT school from `schools` WHERE school= '$school'";
    $schoolRes = mysqli_query($con, $checkSchool);
    $schoolCount = mysqli_num_rows($schoolRes);

    if($schoolCount >0){
        //if school exist get it's id
        $schoolIdSql = "SELECT id from `schools` WHERE school= '$school'";
        $schoolIdRes = mysqli_query($con, $schoolIdSql);
        $schoolRow = mysqli_fetch_array($schoolIdRes);
        $schoolId = $schoolRow['id'];
    }else{
        //if doesn't exist insert new school
        $schoolquery = "INSERT INTO schools (state_id, school) VALUES ('$state','$school')";
        $schoolresult = mysqli_query($con, $schoolquery);
        //get new school id
        $schoolIdSql = "SELECT id from `schools` WHERE school= '$school'";
        $schoolIdRes = mysqli_query($con, $schoolIdSql);
        $schoolRow = mysqli_fetch_array($schoolIdRes);
        $schoolId = $schoolRow['id'];
    }



      //CHECK USER


    $checkUser = "SELECT email from `Users` WHERE email= '$email'";
    $userRes = mysqli_query($con, $checkUser);
    $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($userRes);

    if($userCount >0){
        $submitted = "Email is not available";
        $invalid = '<input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control is-invalid" required="required" data-error="email is required." data-remote="/validate">';

    } else{

        $userId = rand(1,9999999);
        $check_userId ="select count(*) count from Users where user_id = " . $userId;
        while ($row['count'] > 0);



        $query = "INSERT INTO Users (id, user_type, name, lastname, email, phone, school, address, state, zip, password, status) VALUES ('$userId','teacher','$name', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone', '$schoolId', '$address', '$stateName', '$zip', '$hash', 'active')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);


        if(!$result = $con->query($query)){
            die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
        }else {
              header("location: thankyou");
        } 
    }

  }
```

Comment: well I would get rid of this `mysqli_real_escape_string` and instead use prepared statements.  Just for the simple fact you can wipe out several lines.  If you used PDO for example you could wipe out several more....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some old artefacts of earlier programming survived:

Maybe this is the new query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

And maybe this is the old one?

```
if(!$result = $con->query($query))
```

Should do the same and be the cause for the duplicate of the insert.

Comment: those should be the two lines where the insert query is executed twice